How can I call multiple numbers sequentially from a Twilio flow?
I would like to pass a JSON object to the flow that contains names and their phone numbers. The flow should then call each person in the list one by one, greet them by name, and ask a question. If the response is “1” (yes), the flow should end. Any other response should be considered a no, and the next person should be called in the same manner. The people list is different each time.
The problem is that the “Make Outgoing Call” widget cannot be configured; it takes the phone number from the REST request.
I have already tried several different approaches, unfortunately without success:
Writing a function. However, the function cannot run for more than 10 seconds in Twilio.
Using a sub-flow. This also doesn’t work because the sub-flow cannot configure the “To” number; it is inherited from the parent flow.
Is it possible to solve this on the Twilio side without using an external API to orchestrate the calls to Twilio flow with different phone numbers each time?
Thank you in advance!

From the docs "When a Flow is triggered by an incoming message, if the phone number is already associated with a messaging service, you can't use the Make Outgoing Call Widget.". It sounds to me, this is your case. Can you explain what your overall use case is? Why do you want to call all people from the array? I assume it's individual calls and not one large conference call, right?
